# Setting MapReduce Counter value to a certain value

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I don't see a straightforward way of setting a counter value of a MapReduce job in the beginning? Also is the counter increment atomic operation among map/reduce tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by setting a counter value in the beginning - do you mean initializing a counter value at something other than 0 (what's your use case for doing this?).

As for atomic operation, the counters are accumulated in isolation for each task. As tasks complete, the counter values are committed to the global totals (only the committed tasks are committed, so if you have two tasks running speculatively, only the successful task counters are committed.

Comment: Yes, other than 0 is what I want.

Comment: Still not sure why you'd want to do this, but in the setup method for your mapper / reducer, you can pull out the task number from the context, and init the counter value to some value when the task id is 0 (i.e the first mapper / reducer in the series)

Answer (score 1):

Either set the value while you create the counter like :

```
  private AtomicInteger pages = new AtomicInteger(0);  // total pages fetched
```

OR use `incrCounter()` method in a loop if you want to do it at some point later. 
(The first one is better.)

Counters are maintained by the task with which they are associated, and periodically
sent to the tasktracker and then to the jobtracker, so they can be globally aggregated. So each map task / reduce task will have its own copy of counter variable. If the job is successful, the total of all the counters is made and provided in output summary.

Comment: Not sure why you use an AtomicInteger here, since there is only a single thread in a task doing computation

Comment: that was just an example for OP...its upto OP to pick as per the use case